# Getting the Auth0 token

Tags: angular, auth0

I use the Angular SDK of Auth0 and everything is working... except getting the token. Right now I'm using the token you can get by manually from my dashboard.

Auth0Service contains a method called getAccessTokenSilently, but that token is useless and is small(not the right one) I see when my application loads a request to Auth0. Which I don't understand, because I didn't program it anyway that call... but that call has the token!

How do I get the bearer token?

[image]

**Edit code example**
But... altert, the point is that the console.log doesn't contain the right key, or at least does keys don't work the access the backend.

```
  constructor(private auth0Service : Auth0Service) { }

  getToken = () => {
    this.auth0Service.getAccessTokenSilently().subscribe(z => console.log(z));
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide a code sample where you're using this `getAccessTokenSilently` method?

Comment: Yes done, I do get a key, but I don't believe it is the right one. I tried to use it for the back-end but it doesn't work

Comment: I've gone through their code on github and it looks like they're using the same method as you've tried. They use it internally to attach this token to request in their `HttpInterceptor`, so if it's working in other parts of application, it should be working in your code, too. Are you already authenticated?

Comment: Yeah, all other methodes of the object auth0Service work just fine. Like isAuthenticated$, gives true when I'm logged in and false when am not. Also, the data of the backend is unaccesable if not a key is given. The bearer key to test the api that can be found in the dashboard works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered the same issue, where the token obtained from the getAccessTokenSilently method in Auth0 cannot be decoded on https://jwt.io/. ↗ However, after some experimentation, I found that adding the "audience" claim to the token allows it to be properly decoded and parsed.

```
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: '',
      clientId: '',
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
        audience: '', <--- important
      }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `@auth0/auth0-spa-js` library, you can grab the raw token by fetching the id token claims and grabbing the `__raw` property from it. I imagine there's a similar mechanism on the Angular SDK.

```
import createAuth0Client from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';


const auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
    audience: {AUDIENCE},
    domain: {DOMAIN},
    client_id: {CLIENT_ID}
  })

const claimsInfo = await auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims();

const rawToken = claimsInfo.__raw    // (long token)
```